# Worker pod resource limit in spring batch and spring cloud deployer kubernetes

Tags: spring, kubernetes, spring-batch, spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes

I am trying to run a Spring Batch application in kubernetes cluster. I am able to enforce resource limits to the main application pod by placing the following snippet in the deployment yaml:

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 500m
    ephemeral-storage: 500Mi
    memory: 250Mi
```

These settings are getting applied and can be seen in the pod yaml (kubectl edit pod batch).

However, these limits are not propagated to the worker pods. I tried adding the following properties in configmap of batch to set the cpu and memory limits:

```
SPRING.CLOUD.DEPLOYER.KUBERNETES.CPU: 500m
SPRING.CLOUD.DEPLOYER.KUBERNETES.MEMORY: 250Mi
```

However, the worker pods are not getting these limits. I tried providing the following env variables too, but still the limits were not applied to the worker pod:

```
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_KUBERNETES_CPU: 500m
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_KUBERNETES_MEMORY: 250Mi
```

The versions involved are:

- Spring Boot: 2.1.9.RELEASE
- Spring Cloud: 2020.0.1
- Spring Cloud Deployer: 2.5.0
- Spring Cloud Task: 2.1.1.RELEASE
- Kubernetes: 1.21

How can I set these limits?

EDIT: Adding code for DeployerPartitionerHandler:

```
public PartitionHandler partitionHandler(TaskLauncher taskLauncher, JobExplorer jobExplorer) {

    Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource(resourceSpec);

    DeployerPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new DeployerPartitionHandler(taskLauncher, jobExplorer, resource,
            "worker");

    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.profiles.active=worker");
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.cloud.task.initialize.enable=false");
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false");
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.cloud.task.closecontext_enabled=true");
    commandLineArgs.add("--logging.level.root=DEBUG");

    partitionHandler.setCommandLineArgsProvider(new PassThroughCommandLineArgsProvider(commandLineArgs));
    partitionHandler.setEnvironmentVariablesProvider(environmentVariablesProvider());
    partitionHandler.setApplicationName(appName + "worker");
    partitionHandler.setMaxWorkers(maxWorkers);

    return partitionHandler;
}

@Bean
public EnvironmentVariablesProvider environmentVariablesProvider() {
    return new SimpleEnvironmentVariablesProvider(this.environment);
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `DeployerPartitionHandler` to create workers? Please share your code to be able to help you efficiently.

Comment: I don't have any specific implementation of TaskLauncher for kubernetes. It is picking up the default TaskLauncher bean provided by spring cloud deployer kubernetes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `DeployerPartitionHandler` is created using the `new` operator in the `partitionHandler` method, it is not aware of the values from the properties file. The `DeployerPartitionHandler` provides a setter for `deploymentProperties`. You should use this parameter to specify deployment properties for worker tasks.

EDIT: Based on comment by Glenn Renfro

The deployment property should be `spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.limits.cpu` and not `spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.cpu`.

Comment: I am loading the environment though, from environmentVariablesProvider() bean. So would these environment variables not help?
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_KUBERNETES_CPU: 500m
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_KUBERNETES_MEMORY: 250Mi

Comment: I don't think so as those are different things: one is for environment variables to be set on each worker and the other is for deployment properties to be used by the TaskLauncher for each deployed app.

Comment: Is there anything missing to accept this answer? Have you tried to set deploymentProperties on the DeployerPartitionHandler?

Comment: Testing with changes, some issue came in my k8s setup, which is blocking me to test the solution. Will accept the answer soon, after resolving the k8s issue and testing.

Comment: I tried the recommended way.
`@Value("#{${batch.deployer}}")
  private Map<String, String> deployerProp;`

`partitionHandler.setDeploymentProperties(deployerProp);`

The deployerProperties are getting logged and printed on console, but the resource limits are not getting applied to the worker pod.

Comment: Any hints? Am I setting the properties correctly? I have given the following in batch.deployer: `batch.deployer={"spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.cpu":"100m","spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.memory":"500Mi"}`

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response.
It should be `spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.limits.cpu`
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. limits, and requests was missing from the property name.

Comment: Good to hear that it solved your issue. I updated the answer accordingly.